# Is there a way to add aud element in the OAuth 2 with grant type = Auth code with PKCE in postman

Tags: oauth-2.0, postman

I've added Audience parameter from advanced options but I don't see a parameter added in the postman console.

Below is a sample request & highlighted in bold is the parameter that needs to be added on the authorize request in postman.

```
https://{ehr_authorize_url}?
response_type=code&
client_id=app-client-id&
redirect_uri=https://{app_redirect_url} &
launch=123&
scope=openid+fhiruser&
state=abc&
aud=https://{fhir_base_url}&
code_challenge={XXXXXXXXX}&
code_challenge_method=S256
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, Postman doesn't support adding 'aud' in the authorization request. The value you provide in the 'Audience' input of the advanced options will be used as 'audience' parameter in the request body of the token generation endpoint.

However, there's a **workaround** where you can pass the 'aud' in the 'Auth URL' as a query string parameter like this:

[image]

You can do the same for 'Access Token URL' to get a token with 'aud' claim